# Flutter Unit Testing with Mockito multiple stubs

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, mockito

I'm quite new to unit testing and I want to test a method of a service that calls conditionally a second method. The problem I'm facing now is that I'm getting a missing MissingStubError even I have created the missing stub.

mockito: 5.3.2

Error Message:
MissingStubError: 'createCashbookItem'
No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
createCashbookItem(Instance of 'CashbookItem')

Test:

```
@GenerateMocks([CashbookRepository, ReceiptRepository, CashbookItemRepository])
void main() {
  late BookingService bookingService;
  late MockCashbookRepository mockCashbookRepository;
  late MockCashbookItemRepository mockCashbookItemRepository;
  late MockReceiptRepository mockReceiptRepository;

  setUp(() {
    mockCashbookRepository = MockCashbookRepository();
    mockCashbookItemRepository = MockCashbookItemRepository();
    mockReceiptRepository = MockReceiptRepository();
    bookingService = BookingServiceImpl(
      receiptRepository: mockReceiptRepository,
      cashbookItemRepository: mockCashbookItemRepository,
      cashbookRepository: mockCashbookRepository,
    );
  });

  group("bookings", () {
    var t_OldReceipt = Receipt.empty();
    var t_NewReceipt = Receipt.empty();

    test("create booking", () async {
      t_OldReceipt = t_OldReceipt.copyWith(
          amount: 10,
          totalAmount: 10,
          taking: true,
          category: "test",
          taxRate: 0,
          paymentType: kPaymentTypeBar,
          documentNumber: "1",
          taxAmount: 0,
          receiptDate: DateTime.now(),
          year: "2023",
          yearMonth: "20232",
          yearMonthDay: "2023210",
          contact: Contact.empty());
      // arrange

      var cashbookItem = CashbookItem.fromReceipt(t_OldReceipt);

      when(mockReceiptRepository.createReceipt(t_OldReceipt)).thenAnswer((realInvocation) async => const Right(unit));
    
when(mockCashbookItemRepository.createCashbookItem(cashbookItem)).thenAnswer((realInvocation) async => const Right(unit));
      // act
      final result = await bookingService.createBooking(t_OldReceipt);
      // assert
      expect(result, const Right(unit));
    });
  });
}
```

Method that I want to test:

```
  Future<Either<ReceiptFailure, Unit>> createBooking(Receipt receipt) async {
    Either<ReceiptFailure, Unit>? receiptFailureOrSuccess;
    Either<cashbook_failures.CashbookFailure, Unit>? cashbookFailureOrSuccess;

    receiptFailureOrSuccess = await receiptRepository.createReceipt(receipt);

    if (receiptFailureOrSuccess.isLeft()) {
      return receiptFailureOrSuccess;
    }

    if (receipt.paymentType == kPaymentTypeBar) {
      cashbookFailureOrSuccess = await cashbookItemRepository.createCashbookItem(CashbookItem.fromReceipt(receipt));
      if(cashbookFailureOrSuccess.isLeft()){
        receiptRepository.deleteReceipt(receipt.id.value);
        return left(CreateCashbookItemFromReceiptFailure());
      } else {
        return right(unit);
      }
    }
    return receiptFailureOrSuccess;
  }
```

I have added a stub for the error and my assumption was that it is possible to have two stubs in one test. I want to test if the method createCashbookItem inside createBooking is called.

Comment: The stub expects a matching `CashbookItem` argument.  If `CashbookItem` does not provide an `operator==` override, then it will expect the  specific instance you used when creating the stub.

Comment: Do I get it right that when calling final result = await bookingService.createBooking(t_OldReceipt); during execution the same instance is expected as would be created inside the method and because of this I'm facing the missing stub error?

Comment: Yes. `createBooking` calls `cashbookItemRepository.createCashbookItem`, which you tried to create a stub for, but that stub will match only if the `CashBookItem` argument compares equal to the one you used when registering the stub.  Unless you override `CashBookItem.operator ==`, it will compare equal only if the objects are the same instance.  Either provide a `operator ==` (which also would entail providing `hashCode`) or use a different `ArgMatcher` (e.g. [`any`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/any.html)) when registering the stub.